# How to apply CSS only to the parent <a>, excluding the children ones?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply `:hover` on my sidebar links. These links contain an icon and text.

HTML:

```
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
            <a href=""><i data-feather="home"></i><span>Home</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, when I hover the `<span>` or `<i>`, a border is applied to them, while to the whole `<a>` too.

Comment: Can you add your css as well?

Comment: please add the CSS aswell

Comment: We need your css to help you.

Comment: .sidebar-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.sidebar > span {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
    background-color: rgb(209, 209, 209);
}

.sidebar-nav > a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(86, 86, 86);
}

.sidebar-button :hover {
    color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
    border-left: solid 4px gray;
}

Comment: <div class="sidebar shadow-fine ">
            <span>Páginas</span>
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <a class="sidebar-button" href=""><i data-feather="home"></i>Início</a>
                <a class="sidebar-button" href=""><i data-feather="calendar"></i>Agenda</a>
                <a class="sidebar-button" href=""><i data-feather="user-plus"></i>Cadastro</a>
                <a class="sidebar-button" href=""><i data-feather="users"></i>Clientes</a>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: Maybe it is unorganized. Begginer at StackOverflow. But here it is. Another HTML and CSS, where the hover is not operating how it is expected. Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` element contains the other elements, and you are applying that style to the container.

If you can't change the HTML, try this CSS selector to apply the style just to the portion inside the `<span>` while hovering anywhere over the `<a>` element:

```
.sidebar-nav a:hover > span {
    /* example hover style */
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a>` should have a class attached to it which should have the `:hover` declared rather than the div's.

However what I think you might be talking about is the blue box that appears when you click an item. This is for accessibility in your web browser. I would advise against removing it but you can manipulate how it appears by using the `:focus` tag.

[This link describes the accessibility features in more detail](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-remove-css-outlines-in-an-accessible-manner/)